# Jquery clone event handling not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to retrieve the index of the row when the user has clicked on the check box. It works for the codes that I have written for the first two rows when the check box are ticked. However when I tried to insert more rows, the index that I retrieve after the check box is tick gave me a false result, i.e -1.

Can anyone help me with this? I have research for a long time and I still can't get it to work. I tried setting the clone argument to true but it still failed.

```
//Insert a new row after the last row in the table
    $("#add").click(function() {
        clickCount++;
        var numRows = $('#getnumRows').val();
        var index = $('#mytable tbody>tr:last td:nth-child(2)').text();
        var i=Number(index);
        var intNumRow=Number(numRows)+i;
        for (; i < intNumRow; i++) 
            {                               
              $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true,true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
              //$("#mytable tbody>tr>td:last td:nth-child(1)").children('input').addClass('chkbox');
              $('#mytable tbody>tr:last td:nth-child(2)').text(i+1);
              var input= $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').find('td').children('input');
             input.val('');
             input.attr("checked", false);

            }
    });//end click tag

    var chkBox=$("#mytable tbody>tr>td ").children('.chkbox');
    chkBox.on('click',null,function () 
    {
     var isChecked=$('.chkbox');
     if (isChecked.is(':checked')) {

         var index=chkBox.index(this);
         alert(index); //added alert to intentional check the index  retrieve from the checked checkbox of the row![enter image description here][1]
         var insertNewRow=ajaxNewRowInfo(partNo,serviceName);
             insertNewRow.success(function(data)
            {

             var row=$('#mytable tbody>tr').eq(index);
             for(i=2;i<data.length;i++)
               {    
                $(row.children(' td:nth-child('+(i+3)+')')).children('input').val(data[i]);   
               } 
            });//insertNewRow end tag
                         }//if end tag
          else{
        alert('You Un-Checked it');
              }

      });//chckbox end tag

    <!--Add rows -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label  class="col-sm-1 control-label" style='margin-top:0.6%;'>Rows</label>
        <input class="form-control" style='width:100px;' type='text' id='getnumRows' placeholder='No.of Rows'>
        <button type="submit" id="add" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:200px; margin-top:-35px; ">Add rows</button>
    </div>
     <!------------->
     <tbody>
        <tr id='tableRow1'>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class='chkbox'/></td>
            <td> 1</td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" class="serviceDropdown">
                <option></option>
                <option value='1'>Oil Change Service</option>
                <option value='2'> Tyre Service</option>
                <option value='3'>Vehicle Service</option>
                <option value='4'>Battery Service</option>
                <option value='5'>Clutch Brake Service</option>
                <option value='6'>Suspension Service</option>
                <option value='7'>Brake Service</option>
                <option value='8'>Tuning and Diagnostic Service</option>    
                </select>
            </td>
      </tbody>
```

[The first image shows the alert box which the index of the check box row is able to retrieved. The second image shows when new rows are added through cloning, the index of the alert box shows -1.]
http://postimg.org/image/913o3lyuv/
http://postimg.org/image/fg2p0a5kn/

Comment: `chkBox` only contains a “snapshot” of the checkboxes that where part of the DOM at the point where you assign `$("#mytable tbody>tr>td ").children('.chkbox')` to it, it does not automatically take into account checkboxes you added after that. You need to update that variable after you added new checkboxes to your document.

Comment: (Btw., what’s the point of using `.children` there? `$("#mytable tbody>tr>td>.chkbox')` would achieve the same thing, only using only less function call …)

Comment: I see. Do you know how can I update the value upon adding new checkboxes to my document?

Comment: By assigning the result of the same jQuery selection again …?

Comment: Yup,I got it working by update the chkBox variable.Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score -1):

**Consider Element Indexing w/ jQuery Index()**

Ex. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJRJEg

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
>   jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the
>   position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

HTML

```
<table id="hi">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
      <th>Heading 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$( "table#hi tbody tr" ).click(function() {
  var index = $( "table#hi tbody tr" ).index( this );
  alert(index);
});
```

[DOCUMENTATION](http://api.jquery.com/index/)